# Accessing protected instance variables in subclasses in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, scope

Why if I declare a variable in an @implementation block between the {} brackets, does attempting to access the variable in a subclass yield a compile error?

Comment: Are you declaring the ivar in the `@interface` or `@implementation`?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where you're placing your instance variables.  Modern Objective-C lets you place them in your `@interface` or `@implementation`, or not declare them at all with `@synthesize` and auto-synthesize.

Imagine we have a class A:

**A.h**

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
@protected
    int i;
}
@end
```

**A.m**

```
#import "A.h"

@implementation A
{
@protected
    int j;
}
@end
```

When we declare a subclass `B`, we import the header and can see the declaration of `i`, but since we cannot import the implementation, we cannot know about the declaration of `j`.

The following code produces one error, on the `j` line.

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (int)i {return i;}
- (int)j {return j;}
@end
```

**Update/Additional note**

In addition to implementing classes in their own files (`C.m`) you can declare multiple implementations in a single file.  In this case, these classes can access `@implementation` ivars declared in the superclass:

**C.h**

```
#import "A.h"

@interface C : A
@end
```

**A.m**

```
#import "A.h"
#import "C.h"

@implementation A
{
@protected
    int j;
}
@end

@implementation C
- (int)j {return j;}
@end
```

Comment: ok that's exactly what feedback, but then why give the possibility to declare variables public or protected in the @implementation if not then I can use them?

Comment: If you declare multiple class implementations in a single file, those modifiers become meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables declared in a class's `@implementation` section are private by default, and therefore not visible in subclasses. You can use the `@protected` visibility modifier to change the visibility.

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    int _foo;  // Can't be accessed directly in subclass code.

@protected     
    int _bar;  // Can be accessed directly in subclass code.
    int _baz;  // Can be accessed directly in subclass code.
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I get an error from xcode when I try to access "_bar"